# How to alter OpenLayers map settings?

Tags: 7, hooks, javascript

I'm writing a module that will alter map zoom level and map center based on argument from url. But I cant figure out how the `hook_openlayers_map_alter(&$map = array())` works, I'v tried to test this hook with:

```
function openlayers_mapalter_openlayers_map_alter(&$map = array()) {

    $map->center['initial']['zoom'] = '1';

}
```

but it has no effect on maps. What is the proper way to call this hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using drupal_message to make sure it's being called?

Or calling the hook_openlayers_map_alter() function and using map as an array like so:

```
function hook_openlayers_map_alter(&$map = array()) {
    $map['center'] => array( 'lat' => '0',
                             'lon' => '0',
                             'zoom' => '2'
                           );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear cache to make the hook works.